# date-time picker "svelty-picker " in sveltkit

Tags: typescript, svelte, datetimepicker, sveltekit

I have used svelty-picker for date-time-picker, but i can't push time from the keyboard.

```
<SveltyPicker
    inputClasses="form-control"
    format="yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii"
    bind:value={internalDate}
    i18n={de}
    autoclose
    disabled={abfahrttDisable}
    minuteIncrement="0.1"
/>
```

[image: screenshot]

can someone help me

i did not find the action

Comment: `   import SveltyPicker from 'svelty-picker';`